# Correct approach to use javascript dialog box and executing php

Tags: php, ajax, forms, dialog

I have a form to upload files.
At this moment, if you click upload, some php code is executed to upload the file.
However, I must prompt the user if he wants to replace the file, and this must be done AFTER the program has checked if the file exists.
The problem here is that the only way to create a dialog is using Javascript.

How should I tackle this problem? this is what I thought doing:

1-Use javascript to catch the submit click

2-Use ajax to execute php code that is able to see if the file exists, and return with results

3-If the file exists, prompt the user to see if he wants to replace the file

4a-YES = do another ajax request to upload the file and return with results

5a-Update the webpage using JS with the results ("everything went ok", "there was an ajax error", "the file is too large")

4b-NO = do nothing

Is there a better way? Is this ok?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but if it's what I think, JQuery with Dropzone script is better adapted for your problem.

Comment: Just making sure if there's another way to solve my problem (combining JS and PHP cleanly)

Thanks!